# in ngFor If button in div is clicked then corresponding button in other div is clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material, typescript-typings

[image: slider]

In the above picture i have used ngfor to display matcards when i click on rating button in one div it is effecting in all the corresponding divs how to overcome from that.below is the stackblitz link.
**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdhlxz?file=src%2Fapp%2Frecently-added-courses%2Frecently-added-courses.component.html)**

Comment: yes i posted DEMO is the link

Comment: ok thanks , seems like you are binding  every card rating to same model

Comment: you should be including rating for each course in the `courses`  array and bind to the rating property

Comment: done ! .check the stack bliz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pydvfi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is solved check below code

**Get the index of courses**

```
   <div class="col-md-4 course-slider" *ngFor="let course of courses;let i = index;" id={{course.id}} appSliderItem>
```

**App star rating tag**

```
 <app-star-rating rating="{{course.rating}}" [starCount]="starCount" (ratingUpdated)="onRatingChanged($event, i )">
```

**Component.ts**

```
public onRatingChanged(rating: number, index): void {
    this.courses[index].rating = rating;
}
```

Stackblitz URL - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cex8kq?embed=1
Hope this will help

Comment: how do i reuse the slider component for other items to make new slider with new ngfor list.

Comment: Just create a new component add this slider code into that component and using @Input decorator reuse it from anywhere

Comment: can you please send me the code in stack blitz. how to reuse the slider component  which i have created in stack blitz

Comment: I can guide you how this can be achieved, don't have that much of time to create code on stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot to add rating in your ts file

I have fork and fixed the issue in your stackblitz demo

**[Here is link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgtzyp?file=src%2Fapp%2Frecently-added-courses%2Frecently-added-courses.component.ts)**

Comment: How to make reuse the slider  component for another.